# mysql- c# connection doesn't complete

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mysql-workbench

I have a MVC project. I added MySql.data.dll file to my project. My localhost and mysql database is open. My database's name is `proje` and table is `hasta_bilgileri`.

I searched and tried too many solution but everytime I had different problems. What is the problem with my code? One of the last errors was

> "Access denied for user root"

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=proje;Uid=root;password=123456;");
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select *From hasta_bilgileri", con);
DataSet table = new DataSet();
try
{
    con.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
da.Fill(table, "hasta_bilgileri");
con.Close();
```

Comment: What output do you get here and what do you expect? Are you getting errors? If so, what are they? We need more details.

Comment: In your query shouldn’t there be space after * like”Select * from tablename”

Comment: Why you catch an exception at `con.Open` but not at `da.Fill`?

Comment: One of the last errors was "Access denied for user root".

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30768/access-denied-for-user-root

Comment: I did it but nothing changed @Mohsin Mehmood

Comment: check if user id and password are correct and try to connect to MySql using this credentials directly.

Comment: This is my controller file and I reach it by "localhost:1911/Bolum/hello". Maybe the problem is that?  @TimSchmelter                                                                                               
                                                                                                                      
 public class BolumController : Controller
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            void grid()
            {
                -HERE THE CODE-
            }
            grid();
        }
    }

Comment: I tried, id and password is correct. @JintoJacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not because of your script:

1. Check the password in `con`! If it's correct:
2. In phpmyadmin , in `"User Accounts"` create a new user!
3. Make sure you are defining the `"Host Name"` as `"%"`!
4. Declare a clear password that you can use it later in `con`
5. Check `Global Privileges`!

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)!

Done!

& more about your script:

- `catch(Exception e)` is better to be like this: `catch(MySqlException e)`.
- Use `Finally` after catch exception for closing the connection!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I did your advices and now there is no warning in my code. Now, the problem is I don't show my data (which came from database) in the page. I asked a new question about that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099082/how-can-we-use-the-data-which-came-from-database-in-c-sharp Can you look and answer it? Thank you so much..