# How to handle data that's coming from from database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mysql-connector

I think my connection has no problem. But when I run the program and opened browser with this link "http://localhost:1290/bolum/hello" I reached just

> **Output:** DKLSAJDKLJALSJDLs Q

. How can I use my database data? My model,view,controller files are on the bottom. I removed "using .." lines when writing here.

CONTROLLER

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class BolumController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Hello()
        {
            var bolum = new Hello() { Ad = "Q" };
            Console.WriteLine("success");
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=proje;uid=root;password=123456;");
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From hasta_bilgileri", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try{
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e){
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally {
                da.Fill(ds, "hasta_bilgileri");
                con.Close();
            }
            return View(bolum);
        }
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public string Ad { get; set; }

    }
}
```

VIEW

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.Hello
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        DKLSAJDKLJALSJDLs
        @Model.Ad
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of a `DataSet` - use a `DataReader` and read the data into new instances of your model (and create a List<Hello>` if there are multiple records). But that code belongs in a separate service, not your controller

Comment: I am trying but taking errors like "Connection must be valid and open". Can you write a code sample? @StephenMuecke

Comment: You will find tens of thousands of examples on the web (including [this one](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=332882&seqNum=4))

Comment: Sounds like you tried to read data from the database after you'd closed the connection to it. Maybe just need to move your code around a bit. It's not clear, since you didn't show us what you tried. Anyway yeah basically you need to read the data from the database into your model object. If you want to return a list of things, make the model be a list of those objects